# How to prevent json output of relTargetType in spring-data-rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I'm creating a `@RepositoryRestResource` and export it as rest service as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "myContent", path = "myContent")
public interface MyContentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyContentEntity, Long> {

}
```

Problem: when I request the content, I'm getting the following excerpt:

```
  "content" : [ {
    "value" : [ ],
    "rel" : null,
    "collectionValue" : true,
    "relTargetType" : "com.domain.MyContentEntity"
  } ],
```

Question: how can I prevent to expose the `relTargetType` package and "real" domain name?

Comment: What does MyContentEntity look like?

Comment: MyContentEntity is simply a POJO with getters and setters

Answer (score 1):

### In your POJO:

If you don't want relTargetType in the JSON at all:

```
@JsonIgnore
public String getRelTargetType() {
    return relTargetType;
}
```

If you just want to hide the package:

```
public String getRelTargetType() {
    return relTargetType.split("\\.")[2];
}
```

If you want to hide the package and return a different domain name:

```
public String getRelTargetType() {
    return "AlteredDomainName";
}
```

Comment: @onathan Sterling This relTargetType is not my attribute. Its a EmbeddedWrapper class variable. I am not interested to include this class variable unnecessarily in my POJO. Any other solutions.

Comment: Can you make your own subclass of EmbeddedWrapper and override the `getRelTargetType()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spring Rest Data, but as far as I can tell it uses Jackson for its JSON handling.

If that is indeed the case, I would suggest that your situation calls for the use of [Mix-in annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations), which are intended for controlling the serialization of classes that cannot be modified.

First create a simple mix-in class with the `JsonIgnoreType` annotation set.

```
@JsonIgnoreType
public class OmitType {}
```

Next up, register the mix-in in the `ObjectMapper` instance used. As far as I can tell, you get access to it in Spring Rest Data by following [these instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_adding_custom_de_serializers_to_jackson_s_objectmapper):

> To add your own Jackson configuration to the ObjectMapper used by
>   Spring Data REST, override the configureJacksonObjectMapper method.
>   That method will be passed an ObjectMapper [...]

In the `configureJacksonObjectMapper` method, register the mix-in with the unwanted type like this:

```
objectmapper.addMixIn(RelTargetType.class, OmitType.class);
```

Note that `RelTargetType.class` is just a guess. Change to whatever type the field actually contains. This should make Jackson ignore fields of that specific type whenever it encounters them.

*Added:*

In case the `relTargetType` field in `MyContentEntity` is actually just a string field, the mix-in could be changed to the following instead:

```
public abstract class OmitType {
    @JsonIgnore
    public abstract String getRelTargetType();
}
```

And registering it should be changed to:

```
objectmapper.addMixIn(MyContentEntity.class, OmitType.class);
```